# Issue updating the SQL column on submission of form in PDO PHP

Tags: php, forms, pdo

I am only new to PHP, started last week. The developer who coded this for me uses the PDO method and I am trying to grasp the concept of how this works still. What I am trying to do is update a column in my sql table to the new data that the user has inputted. On submission of the form I need this data to update the sql table.

**basics.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<?php include '../layout/head.php'; ?>

<body>

<?php include '../layout/header.php'; ?>

<form action="basics.php" method="post">

<fieldset>
    <?php echo form_input('Family name','text', 'family_name', 'Family name'); ?>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <?php echo form_input('All given names','text','given_names', 'All given names'); ?>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <?php echo form_country('Country of current residence', 'Country', 'country-residence'); ?>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="address" data-hidden="true">
    <?php echo form_input('Address','text', 'current_address', 'Address'); ?>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="address-suburb" data-hidden="true">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <?php echo form_input('Suburb', 'text', 'current_suburb', 'Suburb'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <?php echo form_input('Postcode', 'number', 'current_postcode', 'Postcode'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="address-city" data-hidden="true">
    <?php echo form_input('City', 'text', 'current_city', 'City'); ?>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="address-state" data-hidden="true">
    <?php echo form_input('State/Province/Region', 'text',  'current_region', 'State/Province/Region'); ?>
</fieldset>

<fieldset data-checkbox-type="hide">
    <?php echo form_single_checkbox('Make postal address the same as residential address','postal-address'); ?>
</fieldset>


    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>




<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $family_name = $_POST["family_name"];
    $given_names = $_POST["given_names"];
    $current_address = $_POST["current_address"];
    $email = $_SESSION['user'];

    $sql = 'UPDATE sf_user (family_name, given_names, current_address) VALUES (:familyname, :givennames, :currentaddress) WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1';

    $values_array = array(
        ':familyname' => $family_name,
        ':givennames' => $given_names,
        ':currentaddress' => $current_address,
        ':email' => $email
    );


    $sf_database->run_query($sql, $values_array);
}
?>




<?php include "../layout/scripts.php"?>
</body>
</html>
```

The `run_query` was created by another developer which has the following code:
**database.php**

```html
public function execute_query() {
        // return true on success, false on failure
        return $this->statement->execute();
    }

    // prepare, bind, and execute query. returns success or fail message
    public function run_query( $sql, $bind_array = null ) {
        $this->query_success = false;

        // prepare statement
        $this->prepare_query( $sql );

        // bind values if provided
        if( !empty($bind_array) ) {
            $this->bind_value( $bind_array );
        }

        // execute
        $execute = $this->execute_query();
        if( $execute ) {
            $return = 'Query successfully run';
            $this->query_success = true;
        } else {
            $return = 'Query failed to execute';
            $this->query_success = false;
        }
        return $return;
    }
```

I know I am missing something, I just don't know what it is and I have no idea where to start.

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: Nothing is submitted or updated on the SQL Database